# Simpler way to get a diff of 2 mySQL tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables with identical fields, 35 identical fields.

I know I can find out what rows do not exist in one of them by using

```
SELECT first.a, first.b, first.c FROM first LEFT JOIN second USING(a,b,c) 
WHERE second.a IS NULL
```

What I am wondering is whether there is any simpler way to write this considering that the table columns and column order are identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM first 
WHERE (a, b, c) NOT IN
(SELECT a, b, c FROM second)
```

It isn't a whole lot simpler, but it may be what you're looking for. <s>Also, your version should be more efficient.</s>

Comment: Actually the `NOT IN` and the `NOT EXISTS` versions are usually more efficient in MySQL.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604042/the-old-in-vs-exists-vs-left-join-where-is-or-is-not-null-performance

Comment: And the link from that question to a blog post about this comparison: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, not in MySQL.

In most modern DBMS's you can use the `MINUS` operator for that:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tablea
MINUS
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tableb
```

But MySQL does not support the `MINUS` operator yet.